# what is the meaning of probability distribution function?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

what is the meaning of probability distribution function? I am struggling to understand it can anyone help me please

Comment: Our highest-voted posts about [tag:pdf] are all directly relevant: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdf?sort=votes.

Comment: @omesaad Perhaps start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function ... (some uses of your term may really refer to any of these)

Answer (score 1):

- For a continuous case:

A cumulative probability distribution function **p** is a function which takes as argument a realization **x** of a random variable **X** and outputs the probability that **X** can be less or equal to this exact value, given that **X** is distributed according to **p**.

A probability density function is intuitively how likely a realization **x** will come from this local sample of **X** compared to other local samples of **X**.

- For a discrete case:

A probability distribution function returns the probability of **X == x**, which is positive on all the support of the function, i.e., all possible **x's**. While in the continuous case the probability of any given **x** is zero.